# how do i insert an Image inline with div without lowering the following div

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some html code for a form that has 4 inputs and then a text area
using bootstrap

What I would like is for it to have am image to the right of two divs without moving one of them down i would like it to appear like the image attached  any example would be so greatly appreciated

code below    images: first one is what I want and the second one is what i am getting

```
<body>
    <div class="col_1">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>    

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Name: </label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control required"/>
                        </div>
                        <img src="Micro%20Pooh.jpg" height="112" width="112" class="image-responsive" />
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Facial Expression: </label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Awesome comment: </label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="col_3">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>
```

[image: what i want]

[image: what I actually have]

Comment: It would really help if you posted some HTML/CSS snippets that you already have. Check out [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or code sample that duplicates what you want to avoid?

Comment: images ok i forgot to add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a table with two cells. Put the `input` fields in the left cell, and the image in the right cell. Like this:

```html
<input type="text" style="width:95%" /><br /><br />
<input type="text" style="width:95%" /><br /><br />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" style="width:95%" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="text" style="width:95%" />
        </td>
        <td><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martin-berube/people/256/baby-icon.png" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<textarea style="width:95%"></textarea>
```

Comment: if i do this it prevents my form from lining up looking being out to the left of everything else

Comment: this does actually work just seems to lose some of my styling thanks for the help greatly appreciated